# View and manipulate the model of a MVC web app through a MVVM client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, mvvm, model

I'm building a MVC web app which will be exclusively acceded through a WPF native client. As I now managed to get those two apps communicating properly I'm now wondering how to correctly view and manipulate objects from the MVC model in my client.

On server's side I have (among others) two classes Application and Category, those classes are configured to have a many to many cardinality :

```
public class Application
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> AppCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Application> AssignedApps { get; set; }
}
```

My client app can do all basic CRUD operation via a webapi controller but I'm wondering how to do things properly.

Let's say I want to show all my categories and their assigned app is the following method Ok or is there a much better war to do thing ?

```
public async void GetCategoryList()
{

    Categories.Clear();

    List<Model.Category> model = null;
    try
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        result = authContext.AcquireToken(AppServiceResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, PromptBehavior.Never);

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(AppServiceBaseAddress + "/api/CategoriesWebApi");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Category>>(jsonString);

            foreach (var cat in model)
            {
                var currentCategory = new Category();
                currentCategory.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID;
                currentCategory.Description = cat.Description;
                foreach (var item in cat.AssignedCIs)
                {
                    currentCategory.AssignedCIs.Add(item);
                }

                Categories.Add(cat);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advices / best practices !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a the refactor with some comments

```cs
//DON'T USE ASYNC/AWAIT WITH VOID NO NO NO NO NO NO
//USE TASK
public async Task GetCategoryList() {
    try {
        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(AppServiceResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, PromptBehavior.Never);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        //make call to web api and get response
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(AppServiceBaseAddress + "/api/CategoriesWebApi");
        //check to make sure there is something to read
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault() > 0) {
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Category>>(jsonString);
            //check to make sure model was deserialized properly and has items
            if(model != null && model.Count > 0) {
                //shouldn't clear till you have something to replace it with
                Categories.Clear();
                foreach (var cat in model) {
                    var currentCategory = new Category();
                    currentCategory.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID;
                    currentCategory.Description = cat.Description;
                    foreach (var item in cat.AssignedCIs) {
                        currentCategory.AssignedCIs.Add(item);
                    }
                    Categories.Add(currentCategory);
                }
            }
        } 
    } catch { //Notify User/UI of error }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser ! In the meantime after having some issues on server side for sending object with many to many Relationship I decided to use autmapper to send DTO object having a list of int containing the IDs of related objects instead of objects themselves. For now, with a small number of objects, loading everything on app startup and filtering / unflattening objects on view request seems ok. Thanks for the advice for asayc await with void, I'll apply it, could you tell me more on the impact of using void with async ?

Comment: This is the article that taught me about avoiding async void http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/